# Local Inference of saved PyTorch models

Tags: python, c++, windows, pytorch, torch

I am interested in performing local (no server or cloud) inference of saved PyTorch models that I can "deploy" (for example, using PyInstaller) to machines that do not have any dependencies. Can someone point me in the correct direction for this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

My goal is to be able create a command-line executable that I can share with collaborators who do not have any idea about Python/programming/Docker/containers and would simply like to infer on the models I send (with the correct data, of course).

EDIT-2:

Requirements from end product:

- No "cloud" or remote processing - data privacy is a critical requirement and processing needs to be local on Windows and/or Linux machines using CPU (GPU would be a huge plus but not required)
- No need for user to install anything (no Python/Docker engine/server/etc.) as this needs to be catered to a non-tech audience

Please comment if further clarifications are needed.

Comment: If the end user's a little bit tech savy, docker would be a nice idea instead of pyinstaller I think. they need to be techsavy only in terms of being able to install docker and run a couple of commands. Though I must mention, this suggestion is purely based on my experience with docker and inexperience with pyinstaller. (I tried it (or was it py2exe, I don't remember) and it was miserable trying to make it work. On Docker however, you can have a cool UI all dependencies everything you need.) I might be completely wrong though about pyinstaller

Comment: Ah yes, I should have mentioned that Dockers are a no-go as well (primarily because of security issues - even Singularity has its own issues). This would be for a fully non-technical crowd.